# Date in EditText should remain its previous value when a call occurs agains for the edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I developed an app to get the history of a vehicle to plot markers in the graph. For getting history, I used to edit text `On Click Listener`. When clicked a popup will appear to show the date dialog.

After getting the input it works fine, but if the edit text is called again the date in the edit text is cleared.

What is the correct method to retain the previous date in the edit text?

**Java:**

```java
try {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_date, null);
    h_from = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h_from);
    h_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_flag = 0;
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
    h_to = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h_to);
    h_to.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_flag = 1;
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
    h_fromtime = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h_fromtime);
    h_fromtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_flag = 3;
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
    h_totime = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h_totime);
    h_totime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_flag = 4;
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    final String datefrom = h_from.getText().toString().trim();
    final String dateto = h_to.getText().toString().trim();
    final CFAlertDialog.Builder builder = new CFAlertDialog.Builder(this).setHeaderView(dialogView).setDialogStyle(CFAlertDialog.CFAlertStyle.NOTIFICATION).setCancelable(false).setTextGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    final CFAlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    builder.addButton("Confirm", -1, -1, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionStyle.POSITIVE, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionAlignment.JUSTIFIED, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (h_from.getText().length() > 0 && h_to.getText().length() > 0 && h_fromtime.getText().length() > 0 && h_totime.getText().length() > 0) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                test();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please Select From, To and Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Replace edittext by textview... Can anyone help